# considering prototype variables as static?

Tags: javascript, prototype

Why is it incorrect to think of variables (and methods) on the prototype as being static? I know that we use the instance to call/change them but if we change them then that change is reflected to *all* instances and not just the instance itself.

```
function Calculator() {
    // constructor defined
    this.add = function(a, b) {
    return a+b;
  }
}

Calculator.prototype.staticvar = 'hello'

c1 = new Calculator();
c2 = new Calculator();

alert(c1.staticvar + ", " + c2.staticvar) // both hello

Calculator.prototype.staticvar = "hey!"

alert(c1.staticvar + ", " + c2.staticvar) // both change to hey!
```

Is it the fact that by definition a static variable can be accessed directly with the class, without the need to create a instance becomes the main reason why variables/functions on a prototype object are not considered static?

Comment: This is a misunderstanding of prototypal inheritance. The prototype *is* an instance and not a class definition. Instances automatically get anything that was set on the prototype. You can think of each new instance as a copy of the prototype object.

Comment: *"I know that we use the instance to call/change them but if we change them then that change is reflected to all instances and not just the instance itself."* If you use an instance to change it, the change is not reflected on all other instances. In your code, you're not changing an instance; you're changing the shared `.prototype`.

Comment: Hey guys, it could very well be "a misunderstanding of prototypal inheritance". If possible, please create answers so i can mark them as correct.

Comment: See [How does JavaScript .prototype work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/572897/how-does-javascript-prototype-work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're not static, they're *inherited*. Static would imply it's accessible via `Calculator.staticvar`, not `calculatorInstance.staticvar`. So to answer your question, yes, it has to do with the fact that you don't need to create an instance variable.

In fact, in ES6 `class`es, this is the case when using the `static` specifier on member methods:

```js
class Calculator {
  static get staticvar(){ return this._staticvar; }
  static set staticvar(value){ return this._staticvar = value; }
}

// "private" property, signified by leading underscore
Calculator._staticvar = 'hello';

console.log(Calculator.staticvar);

Calculator.staticvar = 'hey!';

console.log(Calculator.staticvar);
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript supports prototypical inheritance unlike other programming languages like Java. A function prototype is shared among all instances of the function.

I have modified the code to understand difference.

```
function Calculator() {
    // constructor defined
    this.add = function(a, b) {
        return a+b;
    }
}

Calculator.prototype.staticvar = 'hello';

c1 = new Calculator();
c2 = new Calculator();

alert(c1.staticvar + ", " + c2.staticvar) // both hello

c1.staticvar = "hey!";

alert(c1.staticvar + ", " + c2.staticvar) // alerts hey, hello
```

So instance c1 has its own property staticvar. And c2 doesn't have its own property(staticvar). Hence c2.staticvar referes to its prototype object.

So, changing a property on instance doesn't change property value of other instances.